# What exactly do we write in a test vector?

Tags: verilog

My professor has asked me to write Test vectors for the controller shown in the circuit  below:

[image]

We have not implemented the controller as of now. I want to understand what exactly we write in a test vector. Is this merely all the possible permutation and combination of inputs?  For an AND gate I can write test vectors very easily:

```
Reg A;
Reg B;

   A B
1- 0 0
2- 0 1
3- 1 0
4- 1 1
```

But in the present case I am having different scenarios:

```
1- BLANK =1, CLOCK=1 (some signals defined in spec of the chip TLC5944)

{




}


2- BLANK =0, CLOCK=1

{



}
```

and so on.

Is this the correct approach to write test vectors? Can anybody please suggest me what are the best practices for writing test vectors? and what exactly we write in a test vector?

Answer (score 1):

test vectors sound to me like HDL (hardware description language: VHDL and Verilog).
In general, test vectors mean a listing of all possible inputs and their expected outputs in order to check the correctness of a system.
But you can also write test vectors to check a single given functionality in a complex system.
Keep in mind that for registered systems (those with memory - latches) it becomes more complex than for simple combinatorial systems.
Here is a guide from an FPGA maker to write test vectors:
http://www.actel.com/documents/TestVector_AN.pdf